# Kubernetes: AWS Cluster Autoscaler

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Kubernetes: Aws Cluster Autoscaler is scaling one instance at a time but what If I want to scale up with 2 instances at a time and scale down with 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but this is how I would go about the problem in general:

1. Set up an AWS Autoscaling Group with a [Step Scaling Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#as-scaling-steps). Step Scaling can do the sort of scaling you are after with adding several capacity units (instances), dependent on CloudWatch alarms (which you also will have to set up, both for to trigger scale ups and scale downs).
2. Configure your K8s Autoscaler to point to the ASG created in step 1, either by [tag-based autodiscovery](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/charts/cluster-autoscaler#aws---using-auto-discovery-of-tagged-instance-groups) or [manually](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/charts/cluster-autoscaler#specifying-groups-manually).